# don't understand atquery command script

Tags: database-administration, scripting

I'm using a big-data database. in one of it's tutorial it has recommended  me to use below bash scripts if order to running queries:

> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> # this will launch the real atquery program with the given .sql file
> # note: please adjust INSTALLNAME, HOST and PORT to reflect your installation
> /home/lms/INSTALLNAME/atquery HOST:PORT $*
> ```
>
> Then, start runnable .sql files like the following:
>
> ```
> #!/usr/local/bin/runatquery
> select count(*) from mytable during all
> ```

I don't understand `$*` part of the `/home/lms/INSTALLNAME/atquery HOST:PORT $*`. what will `$*` does?
this was suppose to  create a shell script in order to run a query, but another problem is this is two file (I supposse because we two `#!` in that) so how will this two file help me to run queries? I suppose if we had a script with below code in it, it would do this work to me  better and without confusion:

## !/bin/sh

```
/home/lms/INSTALLNAME/atquery HOST:PORT -e 'select count(*) from mytable during all'
```

Comment: What 'big-data' database are you using? What tutorial are you following?

Comment: sensage as a DW and it's own documentation.

Comment: This question would be best migrated to superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create that script as recommended (you didn't include that, probably right before the script) as a file with the executable bit on, and changing **INSTALLNAME**, **HOST** and **PORT** as per your system requirements.

The `$*` expands to all parameters received by the script.

The second file is an example of how you can create scripts that are run by `runatquery`.